# Zend Framework v2.0 - Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface' not found in Client.php

Tags: php, http, zend-framework2

We have the Zend Framework v2.0 setup alongside a WAMP setup.  We have confirmed that our WAMP is working as expected with a test (echo) file in the localhost.

We would like to make an HTTP Request using the Zend Framework and PHP.  Our .PHP errors out with the following:

"Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface' not found in C:\wamp\bin\php\zend-framework\library\Zend\Http\Client.php on line 32"

Here is our stripped down PHP file:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Http/Client.php';
require_once 'Zend/Http/Response.php';

//...custom HTTP request here not tied to the error

?>
```

This file is located in: C:\wamp\www

The Zend Framework is located: 'C:\wamp\bin\php\zend-framework

It appears that our code is erroring out in the Client.php file when the Client file tries to implement the DispatchableInterface:

```
class Client implements Stdlib\DispatchableInterface
```

Our php.ini has the following setting for the include_path:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\zend-framework\library"
```

Thank you for any help!